# How to use one observable to update another

Tags: angular, observable, state, ngxs

I'm trying to use an observable `favourites$` when building another array of the same type. I am expecting that the `favourites$` observable will be populated with the array of type `Universty` and that I can set a class variable to be updated with it's content. I'm doing that subscribing in the `ngOnInit()`.

In a function of my service, I am trying to iterate over the received list of `University` objects and set a property `isFavourite` value on them if their equivalent object is found within the `favourites$` observable array.

This is not working and I don't know why...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { University } from './university.model';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Store, Select } from '@ngxs/store';
import { FavouritesState } from './state';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UniversityService {
  @Select(FavouritesState.getFavourites) favourites$: Observable<University[]>;

  favs: University[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.favourites$.subscribe(f => {
      console.log('favs updated');
      this.favs = f;
    });
  }

  public getUniversities = (country: string, name: string) : Observable<University[]> => this.http
    .get<University[]>(`http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?country=${country}&name=${name}`)
    .pipe(map(this.produceUniArr));

  private produceUniArr(respData: University[]) {
    const uniArr: University[] = [];
    respData.forEach(element => {
      const uni = new University(element['state-province'], element.country, element.name, element.web_pages, element.domains, element.alpha_two_code);

      const isContains = this.favs?.filter(u => u.country === element.country && u.name === element.name).length > 0;
      console.log(isContains);
      uni.isFavourite = isContains;

      uniArr.push(uni);
    });
    return uniArr;
  }
}
```

The line `console.log(isContains);` always prints out `false` in the dev console.

This line `console.log('favs updated');` never prints out. I was assuming that the use of `subscribe` would cause the `favs` variable to be populated. I am using this incorrectly?

The `getUniversities()` function is called from the search component:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Select, Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { FavouritesState } from '../shared/state';
import { University } from '../shared/university.model';
import { UniversityService } from '../shared/university.service';
import { Results } from '../shared/results.actions';
import { Search } from '../shared/search.actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  @Select(FavouritesState.getFavourites) favourites$: Observable<University[]>;
  @Select(FavouritesState.getSearchResults) searchResults$: Observable<University[]>;
  @Select(FavouritesState.getCountry) country$: Observable<string>;
  @Select(FavouritesState.getSchoolName) schoolName$: Observable<string>;

  favs: University[];
  country: string;
  schoolName: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private universityService: UniversityService, private store: Store) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchResults$.subscribe(res => {
      this.favs = res;
    });
    this.country$.subscribe(c => {
      this.country = c;
    });
    this.schoolName$.subscribe(n => {
      this.schoolName = n;
    });
  }

  doAutoPost(value) {
    console.log(value,this.isLoading , this.country , this.schoolName);
    if (!this.isLoading && this.country !== '' && this.schoolName !== '') {
      this.doPost( { country: this.country, name: this.schoolName } );
    }
    else{
      console.log('not searching');
    }
  }

  isLoading: boolean = false;
  loader: Subscription;

  doPost(postData: { country: string; name: string }): void {
    this.isLoading = true;

    if (this.loader) {
      this.loader.unsubscribe();
      console.log('unsubscribed');
    }

    console.log('loading...');

    this.loader = this.universityService
      .getUniversities(postData.country, postData.name)
      .subscribe(unis => {
        console.log('loaded.');
        this.store.dispatch(new Results.Found(unis));
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
  }
}
```

How can I make use of the `favourites$` array to correctly populate the array of `University` objects which are returned from the `produceUniArr` function? Also, am I using the `favourites$` observable correctly? (My current working knowledge is that `this.favs` should be updated with the favourited list of `Universities` whenever that list changes.)

If it helps, the full source is available [here](https://github.com/HoraceBury/favuni).

Comment: are you sure there are equal objects in both arrays? if so maybe try `this.favs?.find()` instead of filter (should not change anything but I would say it looks better and it might be more efficient)

Comment: @h0p3zz I have updated the post with the component class where the `getUniversities()` function response is subscribed to.

Comment: Btw, this line `console.log('favs updated');` never prints out.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the constructor and `ngOnInit` of the service were not being called (I don't know why) so I had to move all the `@Select` and related logic out into a component.

If someone can explain how to make this work, I will select that post as the answer.

Comment: Try to move the code from the `ngOnInit` (of the Service) into the `constructor`. The ngOnInit is not executed because the Service does not implemente the onInit `interface`... but I do not think there is a good usecase for it or if it even works.

Comment: I put a `console.log()` in both the `ngOnInit()` and the constructor of the service and neither printed anything to the console.

Comment: Yeah the difference is that the constructor has nothing to do with angular so it is not dependent on angular it is called for sure. ngOnInit() is only called if the component ìmplements OnInit`. So I'm pretty sure that if you put it into the constructor and change the `favourites$`-array the Observable is triggered and the `.subscribe`-method is called.